# "Dans ma rue" - when does it mean "in my street" and when "to my street"?

Tags: indications-de-lieu, prépositions

"Dans ma rue" means literally "in my street", but when French mean "to my street", they say "dans ma rue" too. I understand this as an idiom, but I'm often confused of this. It is usually possible to tell from context, but not always: I encountered this on [Duolingo](https://www.duolingo.com/), where I have no more context than the sentence I translate. I would like to learn some clear rules on this.

I'm interrested in usage of any variant of "dans X rue", X doesn't have to be a possessive pronoun (i.e. I'm interrested in "dans la rue" and "dans cette rue" too).

Comment: Without any context, it will be understood as *in my street*. Context will provide the necessary information if the actual meaning is different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're tackling the problem the wrong way.

The meaning of *dans* depends - in English - on the verb used.  If *dans* follows a verb that implies a movement from one place to another then in English they will use whatever verb that English verb requires, it's usually "to" but not always.

> *Je vais dans ma rue*.  I'm going to my street.
>   *Viens dans ma rue.*  Come to my street.
>   *Nous arrivons dans ma rue.*  We're getting to my street/ We're arriving at my street. / We're reaching my street.
>   *Nous entrons dans ma rue.*  We're getting into my street. We're walking / driving /into my street.

If *dans* follows a verb that describes an action that happens within one place, or if it is just used to introduce a place, then it will be translated by "in" in English.

> *Maintenant nous sommes dans ma rue.*
>   *Il y a un restaurant dans ma rue.*
>   *Ça s'est passé dans ma rue.*
>   « *Où est ce restaurant dont tu m'as parlé ? » « Dans ma rue »*

I think it's a question of English and has nothing to do with French....

Comment: It's not a problem of English, it's a problem of French having the same word to mean two different things (`dans` as a position and `dans` as a direction). You are, however, right about the problem being tackling the wrong way: this is not an idiom and has absolutely nothing to do with the complement being *the street*, the difference stands for many possible directions/positions.

Answer (score 0):

as a french native speaker, here's how I'd make the difference:

> « Dans ma rue » means literally "in my street",

this is the general (and litteral) meaning of « dans ma rue »

> but when French mean "to my street", they say « dans ma rue » too.

not necessarily, to my understanding, "`to my street`" is *litterally* translated by « `vers ma rue` ». But « `vers ma rue` » can have a few meanings like "`to my street`", "`around my street`", "`towards my street`"…

When in french we say:

- Où vas-tu ? »
- Je vais dans ma rue ! »

we really mean "I'm going *in* my street", litterally and physically, even though incidentally I'm going *to* my street.

N.B.: I'm not sure what the difference would be between `to my street` and `in my street` for native english speaker ears.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

"dans X rue" is used the same way you would use "in x street" in English when you are talking about something "in X street".

Examples:

Il y a un chien dans ma rue. There is a dog in my street.
Il y a une voiture rouge dans cette rue. There is a red car in this street.

"dans X rue" may also be used the same way you would use "to X street" in English when you are talking about a direction, a place to go to.

Example:

Je me dirige vers cette rue. I'm heading to this street.